# Can a SVN repo path be used on a "git-svn clone" instead of a SVN URL?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

High level,  I am tasked with converting a svndump file to a GIT repository on a linux RHEL-7 box.  The linux box does not have apache installed so I don't have ability to use a SVN URL in my git-svn commands.  I have run "svnadmin load" command have created a SVN repository.

**Bottom line,  how do I run the "git-svn clone" command locally on the linux box without using any SVN URL.**

Right now svn repo is located at /usr/data/

I looked at all other svn-git related stackoverflow entries, but none address this particular issue I am having.   Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+local+URL

Comment: `git svn clone file:///usr/data/`